# Reading input character-by-character appears to be skipping newlines

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I wanted to write a simple function to find all the newlines in an input string in Bash, and this is what I came up with:

```
find_newlines() {
  while IFS= read -r -n 1 c; do
    if [[ "$c" == $'\n' ]]; then
      echo 'FOUND NEWLINE'
    fi
  done
}
```

I thought I did everything I needed to. I set `IFS` to nothing, I passed the `-r` flag, and I forced `read` to read a single character at a time with `-n 1`. However, to my dismay, the following did nothing at all:

```
test_data="this is a
test"

printf "$test_data" | find_newlines
```

I received no output whatsoever. I'm testing under Mac OS X, and I ran this on both Bash version 3.2.57 (the one Apple provides) and 4.3.33 (installed via Homebrew). Both gave the same result.

What do I need to do in order to include newlines when I loop?

Comment: turn on debug with `set -vx` (inside your function). Not guaranteed to solve your problem, but it may give you some insight. Interesting problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `read` even in `-n 1` mode is still reading delimited lines. So when it sees the newline it still considers that a line delimiter and removes it (and leaves you with an empty variable).

```
$ find_newlines() {
    while IFS= read -r -n 1 c; do
        declare -p c;
    done
}
$ printf 'a\nb' | find_newlines
declare -- c="a"
declare -- c=""
declare -- c="b"
```

As indicated in the answer by Cyrus with bash 4.1+<sup>([ref](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061))</sup> you can use the `-N` flag to `read` to avoid this problem.

The `-N` option is documented as (from the Bash Reference Manual entry for [`read`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read)):

> -N nchars
>
> read returns after reading exactly nchars characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input, unless EOF is encountered or read times out. Delimiter characters encountered in the input are not treated specially and do not cause read to return until nchars characters are read.

For non-4.1+ versions of bash (2.04+ it looks like) you can use the `-d` flag to `read` to specify an alternate delimiter to work around this problem. Any delimiter that isn't going to exist in your input will work. The most likely value for that for many input streams is likely to be the `NUL`/`\0` character which you can specify to `read` as `-d ''`.

```
$ find_newlines() {
    while IFS= read -d '' -r -n 1 c; do
        declare -p c;
    done
}
$ printf 'a\nb' | find_newlines
declare -- c="a"
declare -- c="
"
declare -- c="b"
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace read's option `-n` by `-N`.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27424/74329

Comment: Hmm, that appears to work on Bash 4.3 but not 3.2 (`read` does not support the `-N` flag). Is there any way to do this in a way that's backwards-compatible with 3.x?

Comment: Not an option for bash 3.2.57. For that using `-d ''` should work though. The problem is that read is still expecting delimiter characters and eats the newline. So using `-N` to tell `read` not to do that and/or changing the delimiter will "fix" the problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner Aha, using `-d ''` works! I'll accept an answer that includes both `-N` and the solution using `-d` for backwards-compatibility, whether it's a separate answer or just edited into this one (I'd just like it to be comprehensive).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use sed to replace the newline char with some unique symbol that you can later trace. this will work disregarding bash version.

```
enter code here
```

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/@/g' <<< "bla

bla

bla"

bla@bla@bla

Comment: I'd rather not do this because it would require the entire string being loaded before any output could take place, while using `read` allows the output to happen progressively, which is better for very large inputs or real-time piping. This does technically answer the question as-phrased, though.